# stop certain routes instead of completely stopping the whole camel context

Tags: apache-camel, sleep, thread-sleep

I am wondering how can we stop certain routes instead of completely stopping the whole camel context and also is there any other alternative for `Thread.sleep();` method for processing.

I would like to run a route once and stop the context when the route is completed. Currently I do the usual `Thread.sleep(3000)` in the **main Java class** to leave some time for the route to finish.

I saw some documentation saying camel route supports graceful shutdown but if i don't use `Thread.sleep()` route shut downs immediately without processing.

Comment: See this for standalone Camel context: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Answer (score 0):

the [CamelContext has APIs](http://camel.apache.org/lifecycle.html) to stop individual routes (`startRoute(routeId)`, `stopRoute(routeId)`, etc) or you can use [route policies](http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html) for more advanced route control

also, to keep your context running, you don't need to use `Thread.sleep`, just bootstrap the context with [Spring](http://camel.apache.org/spring.html) or using a [Main class](http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html)...

Comment: StartRoute and stopRoute methods are not available in the camel version 3.x+, so this answer is not helpful anymore.

Comment: The `startRoute` and `stopRoute` methods don't seem to be included in the CamelContext interface but they're available in implementations like for example `DefaultCamelContext`  and `OSGiDefaultCamelContext`.